# Mysql - find phrase starting with string and delete all after it

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a database with products and each product also contain a field with its description. Problem is, the old site used a 'funny old SEO technique' in wich manages added a phrase after each product description, take a look below. I'm trying to find the best way to programatically delete this phrase from product's description field using either regex in mysql queries or php.

The text in the field (varchar) is something like this:

> Powder for mixing with water-based paint. 1KG recipients.
>
> All our products have been tested and certified. Buy now from now and
>   we will offer you free shipping for orders above 100 Euros

I need to remove the phrase starting with

> All our products.......

Can I do this directly in mysql or do I need to make a PHP script?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some sample data from that product description column. exact data.

Comment: Here is raw data from "description" field:

<p>Powder for mixing with water-based paint. 1KG recipients.</p>

<hr>

<p>All our products have been tested and certified. Buy now from now and we will offer you free shipping for orders above 100 Euros</p>

P.S: Why doesn't backtics mark the text as code in replies to comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pretty simple way:

```
update productdescriptions pd
    set field = substring_index(pd.field, 'All our products', 1)
    where pd.field like '%All our products%';
```

Comment: You are missing `SET` and table alias `pd` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code

```
update productdescriptions
    set description = substring_index(description, 'All our products', 1)
    where description like '%All our products%';
```